# Function question need clarification (inverse, composition)

Tags: functions, relations, function-and-relation-composition, inverse-function

Need help understanding this question, its related to one problem. Thanks!

The following functions f, g, h are defined:

f:ℝ -> ℝ, ∀x ∈ ℝ, f(x) = x^2.

g: ℕ -> ℕ, ∀x ∈ ℕ, g(x) = x^2.

h: A -> B, ∀x ∈ A, h(x) = x^2. A = {0,1,2,3,4} and B = {0,1,4,9,16}.

> Qn 1: Let P:C -> D be a function, and let U ⊆ C. We denote P_u to mean the restriction of P to U. That is P_u : U -> D, ∀x ∈ U, P_u(x) = P(x).

Which of the following statement is true?

A. ∃U ⊆ ℝ such that f_u = g.

B. ∃U ⊆ ℕ such that g_u = f.

C. ∃U ⊆ A such that h_u = g.

D. ∃U ⊆ A such that h_u = f.

Answer: A (Would like to check what it means by f_u = g? is it f(u) gives the domain of g which is ANY natural number? What does the answer actually mean?)

> Qn 2: Which of the following statements is true?

A: h ∘ h is a relation

B: g^-1 is a function

C: g ∘ g is one-one

Answer: C

(Why A is wrong? Since an example will be 2->4->2. How can I know when a composition is a relation?)

(Why g^-1 isnt a function? Since the range and domain are Natural numbers should it be a function? g is also a bijection to begin with isn't it?)

Comment: 1A means that g is the restriction of f to N.

Comment: 2A because h(3) is not in the domain of h.

Comment: 2B.  No, g is not a bijection.

Comment: But A = {0,1,2,3,4} which include 3 and isn't 3 is the pre-image of 9 under h? Like all the elements are one-one since 0 -> 0, 1 -> 1, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 9, 4 -> 16? :O

Comment: Which are you answering?  1A, 2A or 2B?

Comment: 1A does it mean now using f, the domain is ℕ ?
2B oh g is not onto that's why not bijection

Comment: 1A: I think I get it.  Just to check, are they asking that is it possible for existence of a set U such that U ⊆ ℝ to get to function g.
Is this correct?

Comment: 1A.  That is about for what they are asking.

Comment: 2B.  Yes...........